# How to use arphic-ttf with luatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, chinese

I was previously using the [arphic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arphic) font package with [cjk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cjk) for Chinese in pdftex. For LuaTeX CJK, I understand [luatexja](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatexja) is the package to use. I also see [arphic-ttf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arphic-ttf). So, I'd like to try to use these.

It's not obvious how, though. `\usepackage{arphic-ttf}` resulted in error `LaTeX Error: File 'arphic-ttf.sty' not found.` The documentation doesn't say much.

How do I use these arphic ttf fonts with luatexja, preferrably without having to install them first?

Comment: the package contains only fonts, there is no style.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's right. So, how do I use this package?

Comment: Something like `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}` together with `\setmainjfont{...}` with the dots replaced by the font name of the desired arphic font should get you started. You will have to install the fonts, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the PostScript Name of otf/ttf fonts using `luatexja-fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{BousungEG-Light-GB}% gbsn00lp.ttf
\setsansjfont{GBZenKai-Medium}% gkai00mp.ttf
\begin{document}
你好！\textgt{你好！}
\end{document}
```

[image: luatexja+arphic]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the newer, Unicode-encoded fonts AR PL Uming and AR PL Ukai (although both of those are only available under a restrictive license).  They are supported by `ctex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[UTF8, fontset=none]{ctex}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[sf,up,big,center]{titlesec}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\setmainfont{CMU Bright}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{CMU Bright}
\setCJKmainfont{AR PL Uming HK}[
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2]
\setCJKsansfont{AR PL Ukai HK}[
  AutoFakeBold = 1.2]

\title{\sffamily 世界人权宣言}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{序言}

鉴于对人类家庭所有嘅成员固有尊严同埋佢哋嘅平等嘅兼不移嘅权利嘅承认,係世界自由、正义同埋和平嘅基础，

鉴于对人权嘅无视同埋侮蔑经已发展成为野蛮暴行，呢些暴行玷污咗人类嘅良心，而一个人人都有言论同埋信仰自由而且冇惊冇穷嘅世界嘅嚟临，经已俾宣布係普通人民嘅最高心愿，鉴于为咗使人类唔至迫不得已铤而走险对暴政同埋迫害进行反叛，有必要使人权受到法治嘅保护，

鉴于有必要促进各国友好关系嘅发展，
\end{document}
```

[image: UMing + UKai sample]

This should be an excerpt from the UN Declaration of Human Rights.  The fonts come in four regional variants.